# Processing Depth images

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

Is it possible to process Depth images (images with Depth metadata or 3D images) with Autodesk Reality Capture? If yes - which format shall I use for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Only JPEG images are supported ([documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/)).